# Android SecurityException: Admin does not own the profile

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-securityexception

I have a device manager application and I am trying to use setScreenCaptureDisabled(..) function of DevicePolicyManager class available since API 21.

```
DevicePolicyManager pManager = (android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
pManager.setScreenCaptureDisabled(admin.getReceiverName(), true);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
03-30 13:50:24.623: E/AndroidRuntime(11564): 
java.lang.SecurityException: Admin 
ComponentInfo{com.example.xxv/com.example.xxv.DeviceAdminReceiver} 
does not own the profile
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

If there is any permission required, can you please indicate what it is.

Answer (score 12):

Your app needs to become either the device owner or profile owner.  The easiest way to do this for one device is to use adb as here:

http://florent-dupont.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html

Basically from a command prompt

```
adb shell 
dpm set-device-owner com.foo.deviceowner/.DeviceAdminRcvr
```

where `com.foo.deviceowner` is your app package, and `DeviceAdminRcvr` is the `DeviceAdminReceiver` in your package.  Note that you will get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` unless you have removed all accounts from the device (`Settings` > `Accounts`).

The other method is to create a NFC provisioning app as:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision.html

Comment: can we execute 'dpm set-device-owner' command pro-grammatically...?

Comment: @Dhruv no, you cannot. You only can manage a device via adb (either via usb or nfc).

Comment: is still this command working in android 10 or does it need an EMM account!

Answer (score 1):

I think  that you need to setup Profile with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(**ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE**);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROVISIONING_DEVICE_ADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME,
activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PROVISION_MANAGED_PROFILE);
    activity.finish();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Stopping.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you correctly Registered as `DeviceAdminReceiver`?

As per the Android Documentation [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setScreenCaptureDisabled(android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean)), The calling device admin must be a device or profile owner. If it is not, a security exception will be thrown.

And from the Logs it is clear that you don't OWN the Profile!

Comment: @AshokBijoyDebnath did you ever find out this answer? How to own the profile?